# Why my content won't clear this flex element?

Tags: html, css

In the snippet below, I have a slider, which works great. There's an h2 that is placed after the `primary-content` class. The content outside of the `.primary-content' class won't clear the container. I don't understand why.

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".testimonial__item"),
        button = document.getElementById("button"),
        arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".icon"),
        carouselCount = 0,
        scrollInterval,
        interval = 5000;

    arrows[0].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        carouselCount -= 100;
        slider();
        if (e.type !== "autoClick") {
            clearInterval(scrollInterval);
            scrollInterval = setInterval(interval);
        }
    });
    arrows[1].addEventListener("click", sliderEvent);

    function sliderEvent(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        carouselCount += 100;
        slider();
    }

    function slider() {
        switch (carouselCount) {
            case -100:
                carouselCount = 0;
                break;
            case 300:
                carouselCount = 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        console.log(carouselCount);
        for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i += 1) {
            slides[i].setAttribute(
                "style",
                "transform:translateX(-" + carouselCount + "%)"
            );
        }
    }
  
    // set timing of dispatch click events
    scrollInterval = setInterval(interval);
})();
```

```css
/* Duru Sans */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Duru+Sans&display=swap");
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Duru Sans", sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  padding: 5px;
  background: fuchsia;
  width: fit-content;
}

h4 {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.img-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.primary-content {
  padding: 2em;
}

.testimonial__carousel {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: clip;
}
.testimonial__carousel--top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .testimonial__carousel--top {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .testimonial__carousel {
    max-height: 320px;
  }
}
.testimonial__icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.testimonial__icons button.icon {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}
.testimonial__icons button.icon-left {
  margin-right: 1.25rem;
}
.testimonial__icons button.icon img {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
.testimonial__items {
  flex: 1;
  color: #000;
}
.testimonial__item {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  background: #f2f5f9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .testimonial__item {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
.testimonial__item.first {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.testimonial__item.second {
  left: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.testimonial__item.third {
  left: 200%;
  position: absolute;
}
.testimonial__img {
  min-width: 40%;
}
.testimonial__content {
  background: #f2f5f9;
  padding: 2.75rem 2.5rem 2.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .testimonial__content {
    padding: 3.5rem;
  }
}
.testimonial__credits {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  border-left: 4px solid #005fec;
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
}
.testimonial__name {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="primary-content">
    <h4>Testimonials</h4>
    <div class="testimonial__carousel">
        <div class="testimonial__carousel--top">
            <h3>People love it here. See why</h3>
            <div class="testimonial__icons">
                <button class="icon icon-left">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Feather-arrows-arrow-left.svg/768px-Feather-arrows-arrow-left.svg.png" alt="">
                </button>
                <button class="icon icon-right">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Feather-arrows-arrow-right.svg/1200px-Feather-arrows-arrow-right.svg.png" alt="">
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial__items">
            <div class="testimonial__item first">
                <div class="testimonial__img">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/heroes/case-study/Case-Study-Conan-hero.jpg?w=336&h=412&auto=format&crop=focalpoint&fit=crop&fp-x=.75&fp-z=1.3&fp-y=.39" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="testimonial__content">
                    <div class="testimonial__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti laboriosam fugiat perferendis blanditiis, dignissimos temporibus sunt aliquam sequi quia! Deleniti earum quibusdam dolorem accusantium ipsum?</div>
                    <div class="testimonial__credits">
                        <span class="testimonial__name kicker kicker--bold">Lorem, ipsum.</span>
                        <span class="testimonial__position kicker kicker--light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                            Burbank,
                            CA</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="testimonial__item second">
                <div class="testimonial__img">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://sandbox-uploads.imgix.net/u/1630477471-dd0cd5b16967417586c822d6dabcb995?w=336&h=412&auto=format&crop=focalpoint&fit=crop" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="testimonial__content">
                    <div class="testimonial__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti laboriosam fugiat perferendis blanditiis, dignissimos temporibus sunt aliquam sequi quia! Deleniti earum quibusdam dolorem accusantium ipsum?</div>
                    <div class="testimonial__credits">
                        <span class="testimonial__name kicker kicker--bold">Lorem, ipsum.</span>
                        <span class="testimonial__position kicker kicker--light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                            Burbank,
                            CA</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="testimonial__item third">
                <div class="testimonial__img">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://sandbox-uploads.imgix.net/u/1630477587-e54d61f4eef5e36c72dccd1fc0463514?w=336&h=412&auto=format&crop=focalpoint&fit=crop" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="testimonial__content">
                    <div class="testimonial__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti laboriosam fugiat perferendis blanditiis, dignissimos temporibus sunt aliquam sequi quia! Deleniti earum quibusdam dolorem accusantium ipsum?</div>
                    <div class="testimonial__credits">
                        <span class="testimonial__name kicker kicker--bold">Lorem, ipsum.</span>
                        <span class="testimonial__position kicker kicker--light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                            Burbank,
                            CA</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test-flex-parent">
    <h2 class="flex-child">Hello</h2>
    <h2 class="flex-child">World</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you're using absolute positioning.

Comment: Can you think of a way that I can continue to use this slider without absolute positioning?

Comment: @Millhorn Maybe it's easier to just use bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/carousel/#with-controls or https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#with-controls